# Meteor/Mongo missing writes for my tagging system?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm building a notepad, and with each note entry, there is an array of tags built into it. For each tag, we then create a new Mongo entry to "denormalize" the count. So:

```
    if (tag === null) { 
            // do nothing
    } else {

        // Check if tag exists
        // If no,  create it
        // If yes, increase the count
        if (Tags.findOne({owner: Meteor.userId(), name: tag}) === undefined) {
            var newTag = {
                owner: Meteor.userId(),
                name:  tag,
                count: 1
            };
            Tags.insert(newTag);
        } else {
            Tags.update({owner: Meteor.userId(), name: tag}, {$inc: {count: 1}});   
        };
    }
```

That works great until I try to delete tags:

```
    var deletedEntry = Entries.findOne(entryID);

    Tags.update({owner: Meteor.userId(), name: deletedEntry.tags[0]}, {$inc: {count: -1}}); 
    Tags.update({owner: Meteor.userId(), name: deletedEntry.tags[1]}, {$inc: {count: -1}}); 
    Tags.update({owner: Meteor.userId(), name: deletedEntry.tags[2]}, {$inc: {count: -1}}); 
    Tags.update({owner: Meteor.userId(), name: deletedEntry.tags[3]}, {$inc: {count: -1}}); 

    Entries.remove(entryID);
```

It basically skips decreasing the count of some tags. It's random, and mind boggling. I'm using Modulus + MongoHQ for the hosting. I would much appreciate if you guys can help.

Answer (score 0):

In Mongo, if an update statement is going to modify multiple documents you need to pass the option multi set to true, by default it only updates the first document that matches the selector ([docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/modify-documents/)).
Example:

```
Tags.update({
    owner: Meteor.userId(),
    name: { $in: deletedEntry.tags }
}, {
    $inc: {count: -1}
}, { multi: true });
```

Comment: Technically there should only be one Tag document for each user ID and tag. Under no other circumstances would the application create one.

Comment: I don't see how that could be happening then. I have revised my answer to show you a way to do this with only one update statement instead of four. See if that works for you.

Comment: That may have done it. It's a really odd bug, only happens once in a while. It's not like the server is that active. But I'll keep you posted if I see it / learn something new.